# Как отфильтровать список, убрав все элементы списка исключений?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    paths:
      - "/home/vagratn/.ansible"
      - path-one
      - path-two
      - path-three
      - "/home/vagrant/.ssh"
      - "/home/vagratn/"
    patterns:
      - ".*ssh.*"
      - ".*ansible.*"
      - ".*one.*"

  tasks:
    - name: set empty list
      set_fact:
        files_to_be_removed: [  ]

    - set_fact:
        files_to_be_removed: |
          {{ paths
          |reject("search", item)
          |list }}
      with_items:
        - "{{ patterns }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ files_to_be_removed }}"

...
```

Выдает список только c убранным последним значением из списка `patterns`

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "/home/vagratn/.ansible",
        "path-two",
        "path-three",
        "/home/vagrant/.ssh",
        "/home/vagratn/"
    ]
}
```

Как получить список такого вида, после применения фильтра(ов)?

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "path-two",
        "path-three",
        "/home/vagratn/"
    ]
}
```